# Progress Openedge to Postgresql conversion - missing help and description fields

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion, openedge

I have converted a Progress Openedge to a Postgresql DB.
Progress Openedge uses DF files and here is a section from a DF file:

```
ADD FIELD "StatusId" OF "ResultExport" AS integer 
DESCRIPTION "System sets value to 1 on creation"
FORMAT "z9"
INITIAL "1"
LABEL "Status"
MAX-WIDTH 4
COLUMN-LABEL "Status"
HELP "Processing status of this record"
ORDER 30
```

whereas in the Postgresql DB I simply get:

```
statusid integer,
```

The conversion is successful but I am missing the Description and Help that was in the Progress Openedge DB but is not in the Postgresql SQL DB. Is it possible to get this? Do I need to create some other fields in PostgreSQL and manually input the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put those in a [column comment](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-comment.html):

> `COMMENT` stores a comment about a database object.
>   [...]
>   Comments can be viewed using psql's `\d` family of commands. Other user interfaces to retrieve comments can be built atop the same built-in functions that psql uses, namely `obj_description`, `col_description`, and `shobj_description`

You can only have one comment per object though so you'd have to combine your description and help into one string:

```
comment on column "ResultExport"."StatusId" is 'Processing status of this record. System sets value to 1 on creation.'
```